# Can I use Present Perfect tense and Past simple tense in the same sentence?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I am struggling with the use of both present perfect and past simple tenses in the same line, which I will add to my **formal** writing.

I just want to know if the following sentence is grammatically correct and meaningful:

"Dr. Gregory's works on AI **have introduced** me to several questions that I never **considered** before"

Please help... Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This is totally acceptable.  For one, the simple past (aorist) considered is in a different clause, so it's a whole other little idea.  You've got one completed action "have introduced" and one past action.  You could put any tense here that appropriately describes the action.  It could be future . . .

". . . that I will never answer."